# in R, what's the difference between x[with(x, order(x$CHROM)), ] and x[ order(x$CHROM)) , ]

Tags: r, with-statement

I tried the two commands and they return the same results, I just want to know what's the possible difference between the two R commands:

```
x[with(x, order(x$CHROM)), ]
x[        order(x$CHROM) , ]
```

An example can be run online is :
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/with

```
mtcars[with(mtcars, order(mtcars$cyl)), ]
mtcars[             order(mtcars$cyl) , ]
```

Comment: I think the first command should be : `x[with(x, order(CHROM)), ]`

Comment: I tried your version and it produce the same results. If so, does the command x[with(x, order(CHROM)), ] and x[order(X$CHROM), ] are equivalent?

Comment: Usually you use `with(x)` so you don't have to type `x$`. The first command seems unnecessarily redundant. Basically the `with()` is doing nothing.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference. `with` is kind of a convenience function.

### Example 1

You could do this

```
iris[order(iris$Species), ]
```

Note that you have to refer to the `Species` column by using the `$` separator. Using `with`, we can instead write:

```
with(iris, iris[order(Species), ])
```

From an end user perspective, the above is essentially the same as doing this:

```
attach(iris)
iris[order(Species), ]
detach(iris)
```

We should **avoid** using `attach` though - I'm only showing it here for instructional purposes - because it often leads to headaches with namespace/scope (what variables are available - e. g. if you had a variable named `Species` and did the above `attach()` call, there would be a naming conflict). Using `with` avoids this kind of thing while still allowing you to avoid using `$` everywhere.

### Example 2

You could write:

```
plot(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Petal.Length)
```

But with with:

```
with(iris, plot(Petal.Width, Petal.Length))
```

There's no huge gain from using `with` in these small examples. But if you are doing more complicated function calls where you're constantly referring to different columns of a data frame, `with` comes in handy.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first command should be :

```
mtcars[with(mtcars, order(cyl)), ]
```

and the second is :

```
mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl) , ]
```

Both of them return the same result and are equivalent however, the benefit of using `with` is that you don't have to refer the dataframe name again and again when referring to column name.

Imagine you want to order by 3 variables. Using `with` you can do :

```
mtcars[with(mtcars, order(cyl, am, vs)), ]
```

and without `with` :

```
mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am, mtcars$vs) , ]
```

It is matter of choice what you want to use but both of them return the same result :

```
identical(mtcars[with(mtcars, order(cyl, am, vs)), ],
          mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am, mtcars$vs) , ])
#[1] TRUE
```